# ¿Por qué mi reporte hecho con Crystal Reports no funciona en Windows 7 pero sí en Windows 10?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, sap, windows7

**Buenas, he creado un proyecto en `C#` con `Windows-Form` usando conexiones a `SQL`. Para el mismo he usado **SAP**, a la hora de crear el **.exe** me ha funcionado todo de maravilla en **W10** pero al intentar usar mi sistema en **W7** (en el momento de querer cargar el reporte) me ha salido el siguiente anuncio:

```
Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

***** Texto de la excepción *****
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No se abrió el documento.
   en CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()
   en CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()
   en CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   en CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   en ProvidusApp.ReporteCertificado.cargarReporteParcial(String codigo_usuario, String combo_org, Int32 plan)
   en ProvidusApp.ReporteCertificado..ctor(String codUsu, String codOrg, Int32 valortipo)
   en ProvidusApp.ProvidusTodos.btnAutos_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


***** Ensamblados cargados *****
mscorlib
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.4069.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ProvidusApp
    Versión del ensamblado: 1.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 1.0.0.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/ProvidusApp.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.4042.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.Shared.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
log4net
    Versión del ensamblado: 1.2.10.0
    Versión Win32: 1.2.10.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/log4net/1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304/log4net.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
    Versión del ensamblado: 13.0.4000.0
    Versión Win32: 13.0.29.3671
    Código base: file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/EWPOV3J4.R90/PPY01CRV.CM7/prov..tion_e8f1bf3f728a5c5f_0001.0000_d155b7e795049c99/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.DLL
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

***** Depuración JIT *****
Para habilitar la depuración Just In Time (JIT), el archivo de configuración de esta
aplicación o equipo (machine.config) debe tener el
valor jitDebugging establecido en la sección system.windows.forms.
La aplicación también se debe compilar con la depuración
habilitada

Por ejemplo:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Cuando esté habilitada la depuración JIT, cualquier excepción no controlada
se enviará al depurador JIT registrado en el equipo
en lugar de controlarlo mediante el cuadro de diálogo.
```

Este reporte se carga desde una unidad de red compartida y lo he estado haciendo así:

```
public partial class ReporteCertificado : Form
{
    private string rutaARchivo = @"Z:\Reportes\Certificados\CertificadosInterior.rpt";

    public ReporteCertificado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ReporteCertificado(string codUsu, string codOrg, int valortipo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cargarReporteParcial(codUsu, codOrg, valortipo);
    }

    private void cargarReporteParcial(string codigo_usuario, string combo_org, int plan)
    {
        string ruta = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, rutaARchivo);
        ReportDocument oRep = new ReportDocument();
        oRep.Load(ruta);
        oRep.SetDatabaseLogon("prvdsr", "");
        ParameterFieldDefinitions pfds;
        ParameterFieldDefinition pfd;
        ParameterValues pvs = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pdv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pdv.Value = codigo_usuario;
        pfds = oRep.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        pfd = pfds["@cod_usuario"];
        pvs.Add(pdv);
        pfd.ApplyCurrentValues(pvs);

        pdv.Value = combo_org;
        pfds = oRep.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        pfd = pfds["@cod_org"];
        pvs.Add(pdv);
        pfd.ApplyCurrentValues(pvs);

        pdv.Value = plan;
        pfds = oRep.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        pfd = pfds["@cantplan"];
        pvs.Add(pdv);
        pfd.ApplyCurrentValues(pvs);

        CrystalReporteCertificado.ReportSource = oRep;
        CrystalReporteCertificado.Refresh();
    }
}
```

¿Alguien podría decirme por qué me funciona en **W10** y en **W7** no? Cabe aclarar que todos tienen acceso a la ruta de la unidad virtual por lo que no debería haber problema pero como ven, no carga. ¿Alguien sabe o alguien ha tenido este inconveniente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te está indicando el problema, en la primera línea:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No se abrió el documento.
```

El error te está diciendo que el reporte no se pudo cargar. Lo único que se me ocurre, al ver tu código, es que tu reporte no está en el mismo lugar donde estás corriendo tu aplicación en tu ambiente de pruebas. es decir, en esta línea:

```
private string rutaARchivo = @"Z:\Reportes\Certificados\CertificadosInterior.rpt";
```

Si lo quieres mantener así, tendrías que asegurarte que donde sea que instales tu aplicación, esa ruta y archivo exista. Lo que te podría recomendar, es que, todos tus reportes los tengas dentro de tu aplicación, y accedes a el path directamente iniciando del directorio raíz del proyecto. Suponiendo que crees dentro de tu proyecto, un directorio similar al que tienes actualmente, la línea de código antes mencionada quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
private string rutaARchivo = @"~\Certificados\CertificadosInterior.rpt";
```

El prefijo `~` es equivalente al path donde se encuentra tu aplicación. La ventaja de este es que, puedes mover tu aplicación de lugar, y siempre se "actualizará" al path donde esté, así que eso evitaría problemas de recursos no encontrados, siempre y cuando sigan dentro de tus archivos de proyecto.

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda. ¡Saludos! :D